# Starting Windows Application vs Console Application via Cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, console-application, windows

I have curiosity question regarding Console vs Windows Application when running the application from the Cmd, calling the exe directly.
If the application is compiled as a Console Application (will refer to it as my *ConApp*), when running the app via the cmd, the prompt waits for the app to complete running before continuing. However if the application has been compiled as an Windows Application (will to refer to it as my *WinApp*), starting the app via cmd the prompt will fire-and-forget the *WinApp*, understandably this is expected behavior.
To get the *WinApp* to stop the cmd from firing-and-forgetting, one would have to start the app in cmd with something like "start \wait WinApp.exe", this will cause the Cmd prompt to wait for *WinApp* to stop running before continuing.
My question around this is how does Console Application inform the Cmd, or how does the Cmd know that it needs to stay open, and not fire-and-forget the *ConApp*? And is it possible to invoke the same kinda of behavior in my *WinApp* ie so that I don't have to call "start \wait"?

Note: 
I have played around with using AllocConsole and AttachConsole, however when using AttachConsole(-1) in my *WinApp*, the Cmd still fire-and-forgets the *WinApp* however the *WinApp* seems to just open a new Console Window.

Comment: Are you interested in the technical details or how to change your program from fire-and-forget mode to wait mode?

Comment: Whether an executable is a console mode app or a native Windows app is recorded in the header of the EXE file.  Cmd.exe looks at it to know what to do.  This won't help you solve anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This information is stored as a part of the `PEOptHeader` portion of the EXE binary format.  Specifically the `Subsystem` field tells the operating system what type of application this is and can have the following values

- 1: Native
- 2: Windows/GUI
- 3: Windows non-GUI
- 5: OS/2
- 7: POSIX

This is what tells windows what type of program it is and hence gives it the ability to make different choices as cmd does.

[Documentation Link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files)

Answer (score 3):

Technical details aside ([JaredPar did a really good job of doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20962017/80274)), if you want to change your program from `Windows/GUI` mode to `Windows non-GUI` all you need to do is go in to your project settings and change the drop-down from "Windows Application" to "Console Application"

[image]

You can have a Window application run as a Console Application and it will give you the behavior you are expecting. (note however, now if you double click on the icon for the program it will open a console window that will stay open while your program is open.)

[image]